# How to execute a command randomly over a given time interval?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am interested in a running a Unix command once randomly over a given time interval.

For example, if the command is `ls` and my time interval is between noon and 2pm, how could I start a background process that would run `ls` in the background once randomly between noon and 2pm?

Answer (score 1):

For your intents, you program a crontab for noon, and then sleep a random interval between 0 and 120 seconds (two hours).

So the crontab line to run a command everyday at noon is:

```
* 12 * * * command.sh
```

and then you start command.sh with:

```
sleep $(( RANDOM % (120*60) ))
```

an alternative is doing:

```
at noon + $(( RANDOM % 120 )) minutes tomorrow
```

at the beginning of the script each day. Needless to say, the latter it is not the best of the ideas as it is bound to fail over time.

Comment: This works only if the timespan is not larger than 32767 seconds. And the modulo usually makes it uneually distributed (which should not be a problem for values below 1000. BTW: You don't need `$` within `$((...))`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Oddly enough my comments and gollum comments disappeared from here.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using the `at` command. Since at allows the use of timespec you can use it like this:

```
at 12:00 PM tomorrow + 30 minutes
```

So in your case you would want to use something like this:

```
at 12:00 PM tomorrow + $(($RANDOM % 120)) minutes
```

After entering this command you can type your commands, e.g. `ls` and finish via `ctrl + d`

If you're not familiar with the at command read [this tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

Comment: Despite documenting it, as I commented out in my answer, this particular solution whilst it is more elegant, it is bound to fail. It depends on working every day for the next day to be programmed.

Comment: Right, but the OP did not say that he wants the command to run every day. In fact he wrote "once".

Comment: I see you are new here... in my sleep I mistook 9 hundred for 1 hundred. I have as an ethic commenting on small oversights and only posting when my answers are really that different from the original. Over time you will see others do that. Anyway you need more points than me. Choose wisely your standing over time. Cheers. (and btw, by the time you copied the at command, Hauke had already commented $RANDOM does not need the $)